# Modding sprites in New Super Mario Bros. DS

Tags: collision-detection, sprites, modding

I'm a New Super Mario Bros. DS modder.

My goal is to create a custom sprite over an existing unused sprite.

I checked in on fellow modders and they said theoretically, I *could* copy another sprite's code to this "new" sprite. They also said they think that the collision manager would be the hardest part.

Does anyone know how I could also copy the other sprite's collision settings to my new sprite?

Comment: Did you try the advice about copying another sprite's code to the new one? Did it work? Did you have any problems with collision after that? Where exactly are you stuck now?

Comment: I'm basically stuck on how to rewrite the code on the unused sprite, since there's no tutorials on this